# MongoDB aggregation: get counts of key, value pairs

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that has documents structured like so:

```
{
  responses: {
    key1: bar,
    key2: quux
    ...
  },...
}
```

Is there a way to get the counts of each unique key, value pair in the `responses` object? For example, I'd like to see results like the following (the exact structure doesn't matter):

```
{
  key1: {
    foo: 7 // aka 7 objects are similar to { responses: [{key: foo}] }
    bar: 30
  },
  key2: {
    baz: 24,
    quux: 13
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know all the key names in advance or no?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the key names -- would make things a lot easier. They're tied to user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.   Aggregation framework cannot do it yet because you cannot map key names to values.  But map reduce makes it relatively straight forward:

```
map = function () { 
       for (k in this.responses) { 
          emit( { key: k, response: this.responses[k]}, 1 ); 
       } 
}

reduce = function (k, values) { 
       result = 0;  
       values.forEach( function(v) { result += v; } ); 
       return result; 
}
```

On this sample dataset:

```
> db.responses.find({},{_id:0,responses:1}).pretty()
{ "responses" : { "key1" : "foo", "key2" : "bar" } }
{ "responses" : { "key1" : "foo", "key3" : "bar" } }
{ "responses" : { "key2" : "foo", "key3" : "bar" } }
{ "responses" : { "key3" : "baz" } }
```

Running MR gets you:

```
> db.responses.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out:{inline:1}})
{
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "key" : "key1",
                "response" : "foo"
            },
            "value" : 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "key" : "key2",
                "response" : "bar"
            },
            "value" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "key" : "key2",
                "response" : "foo"
            },
            "value" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "key" : "key3",
                "response" : "bar"
            },
            "value" : 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "key" : "key3",
                "response" : "baz"
            },
            "value" : 1
        }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 65,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 4,
        "emit" : 7,
        "reduce" : 2,
        "output" : 5
    },
    "ok" : 1,
}
```

Here is the second way to do this via mapreduce - this gives output more like what you said you are looking for:

```
m2 = function () {
    for (k in this.responses) {
      keyname = this.responses[k];
      val = {};
      val[keyname] = 1;
      emit ( k, val );
    }
}
r2 = function (k, values) {
      result = { };
      values.forEach ( function(v) {
          for (k in v) {
             if (result[k] > 0) {
                result[k] += v[k];
             } else {
                result[k] = v[k];
             }
          }
      } );
      return result;
}
```

Results are:

```
> db.responses.mapReduce(m2, r2, {out:{inline:1}})
{
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : "key1",
            "value" : {
                "foo" : 2
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : "key2",
            "value" : {
                "bar" : 1,
                "foo" : 1
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : "key3",
            "value" : {
                "bar" : 2,
                "baz" : 1
            }
        }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 3,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 4,
        "emit" : 7,
        "reduce" : 3,
        "output" : 3
    },
    "ok" : 1,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be accomplished with map reduce. You would find all the keys you wanted to count with your map function and the reduce the results emitted to a count in your reduce function.

This is a good video explanation of map reduce in mongodb of you have not used it before...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WovfjprPD_I