# Mongodb aggregation: distinct count

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm fairly new to the aggregation framework and have got a bit stuck. I was hoping that someone could give me some advice. I've wrangled my data into the form:

```
{ 
    "python" : "2.7.9", 
    "ACmanagerversion" : "TBD", 
    "ACstatusmanager" : "0.13", 
    "ACversion" : "0.9.2"
}
{ 
    "python" : "2.7.9", 
    "ACmanagerversion" : "TBD", 
    "ACstatusmanager" : "0.16", 
    "ACversion" : "0.9.1"
}
{ 
    "python" : "2.7.9", 
    "ACmanagerversion" : "1.1", 
    "ACstatusmanager" : "0.16", 
    "ACversion" : "0.9.1"
}
{ 
    "python" : "2.7.4", 
    "ACmanagerversion" : "1.3", 
    "ACstatusmanager" : "0.16", 
    "ACversion" : "0.9.1"
}
```

I would like to return data of form (or similar):

```
{
"type" : "python",
"2.7.9" : 3,
"2.7.4" : 1
},
{
"type" : "ACversion",
"0.9.1" : 3,
"0.9.2" : 1
}
...
```

(i.e count up all the unique occurrences)

By running:

```
{
    $group: {
        "_id" : "$python", version_count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
}
```

I get

```
{ 
    "_id" : "2.7.6", 
    "version_count" : 1.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : "2.7.9", 
    "version_count" : 36.0
}
```

I just get a bit stuck in turning into a more 'generic' solution where I automatically work out the various bits of software without having to specify one for each type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB Aggregation: Counting distinct fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501064/mongodb-aggregation-counting-distinct-fields)

Comment: sounds like you want to count distinct key - value pairs. Maybe "[MongoDB aggregation: get counts of key, value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492891/mongodb-aggregation-get-counts-of-key-value-pairs)" will help you. If you know what fields you want to count beforehand, i'd recommend looking up [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) for this.This lets you build multiple sub-pipelines on the same set of input documents in a single aggregation stage. So you can put your group stage in each sub-pipeline to get counts for each software type.